# Module 'audioplayers' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-audioplayers

I'm trying to run a flutter application on an ios device and this error shows up `Module 'audioplayers' not found`
i have tried things like clean cache, adding armv7 to the `build setting` on xcode, also confirm multiple times that i was running the `.xcworkspace` and others solutions too, what finally worked for me was changing the ios target number on the deployment info section on xcode.
So it build successfully on a physical ios device, but it still throws the same error when i try to build it on a simulator.

Comment: If arm7 helped try to add i386 x86_64 =)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but i still get the same error

Comment: What do you mean " changing the ios target number on the deployment info section"??? Build version or what?